# Sharepoint Foundation Preview Pane Problem

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, view-styles

I am experiencing an useful problem with a List with "Preview Pane" style.
The field of this List are some "standard" (string) fields and "People or Group" fields.
If all "People or Group" fields are filled, no problem.
When one of the "People or Group" fields is not filled (is blank), then the fields at the bottom of this blank field do not refresh selecting a new element on the list on the left (header), but remain with the old value.

I investigated into js source but I didn't came up with a solution.
Does anyone experienced this problem?

Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If anyone experiences the same problem, I solved with the following JQuery snippet:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {                

    if ($("div[field='LinkTitle']").length>0) {             
        $("div[field='LinkTitle']").attr("onmouseover","OnItem(this); PPFix()");
        var onmouseoverParent = $("div[field='LinkTitle']").parent().attr("onmouseover");
        $("div[field='LinkTitle']").parent().attr("onmouseover",onmouseoverParent+"; PPFix()");
    }
});

function PPFix() {
    $("div.ms-peopleux-vanillauser:visible").siblings().each(function(index) {              
        var content = $(this).html();   
        var dest = $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().eq(index);                           
        $(dest).find("td.ms-formbody").html(content);           
    });
}
```

Comment: Since this code helped you, it would be nice if you could mark your post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution:  If you have an email user/group field that is not completed, it will not display any details beyond that field for each record.  Either remove that email column, or ensure they are filled out.